# Eclipse: Storing info in .project file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to associate information with projects (certain properties). I tried using the persistence store (`getPersistentProperty()` and `setPersistentProperty()`).
The problem with that is that when I export the project and re-import it in a different workspace, those properties are gone (since they are stored somewhere in the `.metadata` folder of the workspace).

So I was thinking that if there's a way to store the info in the `.project` file then this would solve my problem because this file is always included when projects are exported.

Is there an API to do that?

Any pointers would be appreciated! Thank you!

Regards,
T

Comment: I stumbled upon your question and wondered if you could possibly help me with mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649569/storing-persistent-resource-properties-in-version-control which is a bit like yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to consider using a **[configuration scope](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_a_preference_scope%3F)** to store preferences across workspace.
See **[project scope preferences](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resInt_preferences.htm)**.
Using Store (as discussed in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg42275.html)), you also get some details on the nature of a configuration [in this FAQ](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-core/documents/user_settings/faq.html).